# Image on canvas blocks canvas objects movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, razor

I am working on an application where my users are able to add text to a page. Each page is a blank canvas except for an image in the center. I am currently able to place n-amounts of text elements and move each of them, however I'm unable to move a text element on the image. I'm only able to move the text around the image in the whitespaces.

***My canvas is placed on a Razor Partial View, which is opened as a Bootstrap Modal on clicking a button.***

I used the canvas demo of simon sarris as my baseline: http://simonsarris.com/project/canvasdemo/demo1.html . I went back to this to build the fiddle. The way I added the image to the canvas in the fiddle is the same way as I added it in my application.

Where should I look to make changes so that I am able to move my objects anywhere on my canvas?

Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4agpdx6q/2/

**drawText function** (replaces the drawRect function from the demo) (all calculations work, I had to add this to link to the fiddle. Gives you an idea as to what I do).

```
// While draw is called as often as the INTERVAL variable demands,
// It only ever does something if the canvas gets invalidated by our code
function draw() {
    if (canvasValid == false) {
        clear(ctx);
        for (var i = 0; i < textObjects.length; i++) {
            drawText(ctx, textObjects[i]);

        }

        // Add stuff you want drawn on top all the time here
        handleAddRemoveButtonVisiblity();
        handleTextAreaOnSelection();
        canvasValid = true;
    }
}


function drawText(context, textObject) {
    if (textObject.x > WIDTH || textObject.y > HEIGHT) return;
    if (textObject.x < 0 || textObject.y < 0) return;

    context.font = textObject.fontStyle + " " + textObject.fontWeight + " " + textObject.fontSize + " " + textObject.fontFamily;
    context.textAlign = textObject.textAlignment;
    context.fillStyle = textObject.fillColor;
    // ***************************************
    // Draw text in a multi line.
    // ***************************************
    var textWidthDictionary = widthPerLine(textObject);
    var maxWidthOfLine = 0;
    for (textKey in textWidthDictionary) {
        var textWidthValue = textWidthDictionary[textKey];
        if (maxWidthOfLine < textWidthValue) {
            maxWidthOfLine = textWidthValue;
        }
    }
    //var maxWidthOfMultiLineText = maxWidthOfMultiLineText(textObject);
    var lineOffsetY = 0;
    // Loop over text lines. Each line has it's own Width which determines the xPosition.
    var xPosition = textObject.x;
    for (textKey in textWidthDictionary) {
        var textWidthValue = textWidthDictionary[textKey];
        var textLine = textKey;
        // If no Alignment buttons were clicked xPosition remains set to the original position.
        if (alignmentClicked) {
            // Alignment becomes Center from either Left or Right.
            if (textObject.textAlignment == "center") {
                // Left -> Center
                if (lastAlignment == "left") {
                    xPosition = xPosition + (maxWidthOfLine - textWidthValue) / 2;
                }
                // Right -> Center
                if (lastAlignment == "right") {
                    xPosition = xPosition - (maxWidthOfLine - textWidthValue) / 2;
                }
            }
            // Alignment becomes Right from either Left or Center.
            if (textObject.textAlignment == "right") {
                // Left -> Right
                if (lastAlignment == "left") {
                    xPosition = xPosition + maxWidthOfLine - textWidthValue;
                }
                // Center -> Right
                if (lastAlignment == "center") {
                    xPosition = xPosition + (maxWidthOfLine - textWidthValue) / 2;
                }
            }
            // Alignment becomes Left from either Right or Center.
            if (textObject.textAlignment == "left") {
                // Right -> Left
                if (lastAlignment == "right") {
                    xPosition = xPosition - (maxWidthOfLine - textWidthValue);
                }
                // Center -> Left
                if (lastAlignment == "center") {
                    xPosition = xPosition - (maxWidthOfLine - textWidthValue) / 2;
                }

            }
        }
        lineOffsetY += calculateWordDimensions(textObject.text).height;

        context.fillText(textLine, xPosition, textObject.y + lineOffsetY);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you want to move the boxes (Or text) ON the image?

If this is correct, then your solution is a simple

```
z-index: -1;
```

in your .selectedImage CSS, so it is behind the Text/Box.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4agpdx6q/3/

Comment: Unfortunatly it isn't as simple. When I change the z-index the image "disappears". What I didn't mention, and didn't think mattered, was that the canvas is placed on a Bootstrap Modal Dialog. Your solution does work when I call just the View, but not when I call the view in a Modal. Any ideas for a work around?

Comment: I see the problem. As far as I am informed, Modal Dialogs in Bootstrap are on a pretty high z-index.

You can either try to search for the z-index, or you can just try with values.

I have read that 1240 is above a Modal Dialog, so I recommend putting the canvas on z-index 1240 and letting the selectedImage on -1.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4agpdx6q/6/

Please try this and tell me if it solved your problem.

Comment: That worked. I was struggling to find which element to actually set to the z-index of the modal but I ended up finding it. Thanks for the help, it works like a charm :)